# remove one array index if other has the same value?

Tags: php

I have an array as:

```
$check = [
   0 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ]

   1 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'false'
   ]

   2 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ]

   3 => [
     'id' => '2',
     'value' => 'true'
   ]
]
```

Now I want to convert this array into

```
$check = [
   0 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ]

   1 => [
      'id' => '2',
      'value' => 'true'
   ]
]
```

i.e if the indexes of my `check[]` has same `id` value then delete all of them except for any one.

Comment: did you check `array_unique` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/4149098

Comment: @LeszekRepie thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, you have a syntax error in your array. Missing `,` in between
>   arrays and I have corrected your array. See the code below.

The php function you're looking for is [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Pass SORT_REGULAR flag as function's second parameter, it means compare items normally (don't change types)

Check your validated code [**here**](https://eval.in/805171).

**NOTE**: Don't forget to select Php compiler from the dropdown.

```
<?php

$check = [
   0 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ],

   1 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ],

   2 => [
     'id' => '1',
     'value' => 'true'
   ],

   3 => [
     'id' => '2',
     'value' => 'true'
   ]
];
print_r(array_unique($check, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: if i change the  `'value'=>'true'` to `'value'=>'false'` at index 1 then it will not be deleted but i want to delete that too.

Comment: @lakshay Why don't you remove that particular element from the array when ```value=='false'``` & follow the above mention procedure to get the unique result.